# SSL error in send mail

Tags: python, django, ssl

I try send meil drom django/ But Got error
[SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:661)

That my code:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'info@xxxxxxx'

html = render_to_string('email/html/new_order.html', {'order': self, 'image_code': True})

email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    'Greetings from Discovery Russia',
    html,
    DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
    to=[self.user_email, 'info@.xxxxxx'])

email.attach_alternative(html, "text/html")
email.mixed_subtype = 'related'

try:
    email.send()
except SMTPRecipientsRefused:
    pass
```

How i can fix thet?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the email-settings to your **settings.py**? Like this:

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'xxxxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxx'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
EMAIL_PORT = 1025
```